# Counting the matrix groups isomorphic to a finite group

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, orthogonal-matrices

An (orthogonal) linear representation $\rho:G\to\mathrm O(\Bbb R^d)$ of a finite group is a homomorphism of $G$ into the orthogonal group.
I am interested in the resulting matrix group $\mathcal M:=\mathrm{im}(\rho)$. Sometimes, distinct representations of $G$ give me the same matrix group.

**Example.** Consider the cyclic group $C_5=\langle \sigma\rangle$ generated by a single element $\sigma$ of order five. All representations $\rho$ that map

$$\sigma\mapsto R_{2\pi k/5}\quad \text{(the clock-wise rotation of the plane by $2\pi k/5$ around the origin)}$$

for $k\in\{1,...,4\}$ give me the same matrix group, despite some are considered different representations.

Is there some theory that tells me how many essentially distinct (irreducible) matrix groups I can obtain? Let's say that two matrix groups are essentially the same if they are related by conjugation w.r.t. $\mathrm O(\Bbb R^d)$. I would expect something similar to counting the conjugacy classes of $G$ for obtaining the number of essentially different representations of $G$.

Equivalently: how many essentially distinct irreducible matrix groups are there, that are isomorphic to $G$?

Comment: What do you count as "distinct"?  Obviously conjugating inside $O(n)$ lands you in different copies, does that count?

Comment: If $k$ is algebraically closed, then two irreducible representations $\rho$ and $\tau$, both of degree $n$, yield the same conjugacy class of subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_n(k)$ if and only if there exists and automorphism $\phi$ of $G$ such that $\rho=\phi\tau$ (up to change of basis).

Similar, but not quite the same, statements hold for $k$ a different field and $\mathrm{GL}$ replaced by a different classical group. I'd have to check what the exact statement is for orthogonal groups over $\mathbb{R}$, or hopefully someone else will know if any modifications need to be made.

Comment: @user10354138 Conjugations of a matrix group should be considered as essentially the same group.

Comment: Why don't you include a precise mathematical definition of what you mean by "essentially distinct representations" in your post? It seems unreasonable that you expect readers to figure this out for themselves.

Comment: @DerekHolt I included the statement that by "essentially the same" I mean "related by conjugation w.r.t. $\mathrm O(\Bbb R^d)$". Is this better?